# How can public users access PHP files?

Tags: php

How can a public user access the contents of a PHP file that is within the public_html folder? If they know the address, e.g. [www.mysite.com/router.php](http://www.mysite.com/router.php) is it possible for them to download that file?

I am trying to understand if it secure to store things like database keys in PHP files.

Comment: They cannot download the PHP source code of any script in your site's public folders.  Exceptions would be: Apache mod_php breaks and starts serving php as text/plain or downloads; some kind of vulnerability elsewhere on your site that lets them download arbitrary files.  If you want to be extremely safe, put database creds and keys below the document root (public_html) in include files.

Comment: It's common to place almost all PHP files outside of the public root of your web server to avoid serving them as plain text by mistake (as drew010 touched on above).

Comment: So if you say, they cannot download a source file in any way, what is any safer about putting it outside public_html?

Comment: on a very are occasion a webserver could 'break' in a way that it no longer parses the file properly and servers them all as plain text - not something i personally worry about (except for db credentials)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this properly would require writing a book. However in brief:

If your server is properly configured and there are no bugs in your PHP code, then the contents of a PHP file cannot be accessed by the public.

If it's poorly configured or there are bugs, then the contents may be available to any attacker.

Some developers will move their config somewhere outside of the public_html folder, however this does not provide any protection for many common bugs/security flaws, so it's an unnecessary step that you must not rely on.

You should instead make sure that anybody who gains access to the contents of the file cannot do anything with it. For example, properly salt and hash user passwords and encrypt sensitive data (credit cards etc) with a password that is not stored (anywhere) on the server, and have good firewalls on your database server, so that knowing the login credentials does not allow access to the database.

Comment: then vote close as to broad

Comment: @Dagon it's not too broad, I was just explaining why I'm giving an equally broad answer.

Comment: "Answering this properly would require writing a book." make up your mind

Comment: Thank you. `so it's an unnecessary step that you must not rely on` - if you have the chance, can you elaborate on this? If it doesn't truly add security, why does everyone advise it?

Comment: I'm trying to find another thread that covers the process of a web server handing a request over to the PHP interpreter yada yada because I think it can be explained well enough with only a little more information than what you have here and it's quite valuable to understand. If there's not already an answer covering this it may be worthwhile expanding a little further :-)

Comment: @user3822370 not everybody advises it. Only a tiny minority of websites take this step. It does add some security, but not very much. It's up to you how your server is setup, but my advice is to focus on making such an attack not cause any harm rather than trying to prevent it in the first place - since there is no way to prevent attacks.

Comment: @Marty I can think of thousands of simple mistakes that could allow an attacker to read the contents of a private php file, most of them will be possible even if the file is outside public_html. For example any code execution flaw will allow `print file_get_contents('path/to/config')`. Code exec flaws happen all the time.

Comment: Of course - not sure how that has come up though. I was encouraging you to expand your answer slightly to give a rough detail of how Apache (or whatever web server in general) treats a request to a PHP file as that would answer the question perfectly.

Comment: @Marty Apache "handles a request" by applying configuration rules to the request headers and executes whatever behaviour the config says to execute. There are several completely different ways to setup PHP execution and it can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Given that wordpress itself stores the DB connection info [in a php file](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-config-sample.php) is a pretty good warranty that a properly configured web server will not serve that file as a plain text one.

Comment: I would be hesitant to use WordPress as an example of how to do things correctly :-P (Not that anything you've said is invalid).

Comment: I'm just showing some evidence that it's quite safe to keep sensitive credentials in a PHP file itself and the risk of leaking them is pretty low. I'm not saying that WordPress is a best-practices gold standard, but given that it is behind about about 25% of the web sites available, we can assume it doesn't expose easy exploitable security breaches

Comment: mind boggled wordpress security breaches are almost a daily occurrence,

Comment: AFAIK most of them are because of extra themes/plugins. Also, that's why I mentioned *easy exploitable* security breaches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very rough explanation that might help you understand what happens when someone asks for a PHP file over HTTP:

```
+--------+   1.   +--------+    2.    +-----+
|        |  ===>  |        |   ===>   |     |
| Client |        | Apache |          | PHP |
|        |  <===  |        |   <===   |     |
+--------+    4.  +--------+     3.   +-----+
```

1. The client asks your web server for a PHP file.
2. Apache (or your web server of choice) recognizes that the request is for a PHP file and hands the request over to the PHP interpreter.
3. The interpreter sends back to Apache the result of executing the PHP code.
4. Apache forwards the result back to the client.

Your web server is responsible for all traffic coming in over HTTP, so assuming it is correctly configured to hand all requests to a PHP file over to the PHP interpreter, there is no way anyone can view the raw contents of a PHP file.

If you do not have PHP installed or Apache is misconfigured and does not understand what to do with PHP files, those files will be served as plain text instead in which case their contents will be public (steps 2 and 3 will not exist).

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything in php file, just make sure you don't echo any passwords or db credentials. Everything you define in the file such as `$password, $db_host` are private.